# How to make an object in c++ volatile?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, volatile, unordered-map

```
`struct MyClass {
  ~MyClass() {
    // Asynchronously invoke deletion (erase) of entries from my_map;
    // Different entries are deleted in different threads.
    // Need to spin as 'this' object is shared among threads and 
    // destruction of the object will result in seg faults.
    while(my_map.size() > 0); // This spins for ever due to complier optimization.
  }
  unordered_map<key, value> my_map;
};`
```

I have the above class in which elements of the unordered map are deleted asynchronoulsy in the destructor  and I *must* spin/sleep as the object is shared among other threads. I cannot declare `my_map` as `volatile` as it results in compilation errors. What else can I do here ? How do I tell the complier that `my_map.size()` will result in 0 at some point in time. Please do not tell me why/how this design is bad; I cannot change the design as it is bound due to the reason I cannot explain unless I write thousands of lines of code here.

Edit: `my_map` is protected using a version of spinlock. So, threads do grab the spinlock before erasing the entries. Just the `while(my_map.size() > 0);` was the only "naive" spin I had in the code. I converted it to grab the spinlock and then check the size (in a loop) and it worked. Though using a `condition_variable` would be the right way of doing it, we use asynchronous programming model (like SEDA) which binds us to *not* use any sleeping/yeilding calls.

Comment: Consider using a `std::mutex` to protect the map against concurrent access

Comment: What kind of compiler errors you get with `volatile` ?

Comment: `volatile` doesn't do what you think it used to do these days.  Most compilers ignore that keyword and it doesn't make anything more thread safe. The pattern you seek is that you want a std::condition_variable along with a lock/mutex guarding access to `my_map`.  But the weird thing is how does the owning class of `my_map` manage to get destructed while there are still references to its internal members by other threads - that sounds like a design problem.  Have you considered using std::shared_ptr for the map instance?  As others have suggested above, you need a mutex around my_map access.

Comment: Beat me to it. Only thing I'd add is a link to [What is the XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: `volatile` is not the same as `volatile`. http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/volatile-vs-volatile/212701484

Comment: `volatile` does *NOT* mean atomic! You *cannot* use it for thread synchronization. Use `std::atomic` or a lock.

Comment: The [right way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) to do a spinlock in C++. (But a mutex is likely a better choice here)

Comment: What method is used to synchronize the concurrent erasing? I can only assume that there is some synchronization, as having multiple threads erase at the same time without synchronization is undefined behavior. However, I can't imagine what synchronization you are using. A mutex wouldn't allow concurrent erasing. I don't know you would use atomics with an unordered_map. Is it possible that only 1 thread is actually erasing?

Answer (score 4):

`volatile` is not the solution to this problem.  `volatile` has exactly three uses: 1. Accessing memory mapped devices in a driver, 2. signal handlers, 3. setjmp usage.

Read the following, over and over until it sinks in.  `volatile` is useless in multithreading.

A naive spin lock like that has three problems:

1. The compiler is permitted to cache results, therefore you see the "spin forever" behavior you're seeing.
2. In the classic case, you have the risk of a race condition: thread `A` may check the lock variable, find the resource is accessible, but then get pre-empted before setting the lock variable.  Along comes thread `B` who also finds the lock variable showing the resource as accessible, so it then locks it and starts to access the resource,  Then thread `A` wakes back up, locks the variable again, and also accesses the resource.
3. There is a data write order problem.  If a protected variable is written to, and then a lock variable is changed, you have no guarantees that a different thread will not see the protected variable changed even though it may also see the lock variable claiming it has been written.  Both the compiler *and* the Out of order execution on the CPU are permitted do this.

`volatile` only solves the first of these problems, it does nothing to address the other two.  With one caveat, by default MSVC on x86 / x64 adds a memory fence to `volatile` accesses, even though it's not required by the standard.  That happens to solve the third problem, but it still doesn't fix the second one.

The only solutions to all three of these problems involves use of correct synchronization primitives: `std::atomic<>` if you really must spin lock, preferably `std::mutex` and maybe `std::condition_variable` for a lock that will put the thread to sleep till something interesting happens.

Comment: `volatile` *can* also be useful in micro benchmarks since it inhibits optimization and can thus be used to prevent the compiler from optimizing away otherwise unused code that you want to measure. But that's a very niche use case.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That is actually the only case where I ever use `volatile`.